# Combobox to find value using loop

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have userform with combobox 9 when you select combobox9 value it will show all the values into the each boxes and you can updated the textbox 19 value into sheet against the raw of the selected value in combobox9 however problem is if there's the same name e.g. twice same name in combobox9 it will only update the its 1st name on the raw and not the 2nd or even if there is 3 entry in sheet with same name.

Names are in column C and textvalue is updated its name on column H however I need to loop the column H if it is already updated against its name then same name needs to updated which is in new raw.

Below is the vba code I have but it is so far not working

```
If Me.ComboBox9.Value <> "" Then



If VBA.CVar(Application.Match(VBA.CVar(Me.ComboBox9.Value), sh.Range("C:C"), 0)) = True Then

MsgBox "Record Not found for this PO-Number", vbCritical

Exit Sub





Else

i = Application.Match(VBA.CStr(Me.ComboBox9.Value), sh.Range("C:C"), 0)



End If



lCol = Me.ComboBox9.Value

Set findvalue2 = sh.Range("C:C").Find(What:=lCol, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not findvalue2 Is Nothing Then

adr = findvalue2.Address

Do



If findvalue2.Offset(0, -1).Value = Me.TextBox19 Then



sh.Unprotect "1234"

findvalue2.Offset(0, 6).Value = Me.TextBox19.Value = ""

Exit Do

End If

Set findvalue2 = sh.Range("C:C").FindNext(findvalue2)

Loop While findvalue2.Address <> adr

Set findvalue2 = Nothing

End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you are trying to do but assuming you just want the same value from col C in col H when that value is selected in a combobox the beyond should do it.

I replaced your match function as the disadvantage of this function is that it will stop at the first occurrence. Additionally, arrays are much faster when using vba. On a very large dataset you could even further improve beyond code by using a "dictionary".

```
Sub combobox()
    Dim test As String, combobox1 As combobox, names
    Sheets(1).combobox1.List = Sheets(1).Range("c2:c4").Value
    names = Sheets(1).Range("C1:C5").Value2
    
    Dim j As Long, i As Long
    If Sheets(1).combobox1.Value <> "" Then
        Debug.Print Sheets(1).combobox1.Value
        For j = 1 To UBound(names)
            If (names(j, 1) = Sheets(1).combobox1.Value) Then
                Sheets(1).Cells(j, 8).Value2 = names(j, 1)
            End If
        Next j
        
    End If
End Sub
```

best of luck,

Comment: Hi @ceci great it worked and thank you so much for all your help. i have marked as the answer :)